# Stop code for 30 seconds for only the else

Tags: python

I want to be able to go through the if command and pause the else for 30 seconds, but still loop through the while true if command.

```
while True:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.join('imgs', 'CAPTA.jpg'), confidence=0.5) != None:
        #click(851, 322)
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.join('imgs', 'addtocart.jpg'), confidence=0.8) != None:
        playsound(os.path.join('sounds', 'Alarm.mp3'))
        break
    else:
        ptg.hotkey('ctrl', 'r')
        time.sleep(30.0)
```

Comment: Is it not working? How do you know?

Comment: I think he means to run it parallel.

Comment: I think he means to run `ptg.hotkey('ctrl', 'r')` every 30 seconds until the condition inside the `if` is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what you meant, but if you meant to run `ptg.hotkey('ctrl', 'r')` every 30 seconds until the condition is met then the following code will work:

```py
from time import time

last_refresh = time() - 30
while pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.join('imgs', 'addtocart.jpg'), confidence=0.8) is None:
    if time() - last_refresh >= 30:
        last_refresh = time()
        ptg.hotkey('ctrl', 'r')
playsound(os.path.join('sounds', 'Alarm.mp3'))
```

**explenation**
the variable `last_refresh` stores the last time a refresh happend.
While the condition hasn't been met, if it's been more than 30 seconds since the last refresh, refresh and update `last_refresh`.